# Only Flatpak apps can open all websites after connecting to VPN

Tags: fedora, openvpn, vpn, udp, flatpak

I'm using PureVPN app (openvpn/udp). Installed via rpm file. After connecting, If I `ping youtbue.com` it shows:

```
--- youtube.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6149ms
```

but If I ping google.com it will work without any problem.

Some websites work and some not.

If I go to the browsers (Firefox and Brave installed via RPM) they cannot open youtube.com.

Now if I use the flatpak browsers it will open youtube.com without any problem.

I even tried GNOME boxes which is installed as Flatpak and used the same Fedora 34 as host and it will open youtube.com.

What is the problem? how can I fix it?

```
ifconfig
...
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.xx.xx.xxx  netmask 255.255.255.224  destination xxx.xx.xxx.xx
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 103978  bytes 135509956 (129.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 61682  bytes 4764217 (4.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
...
```

```
journalctl -fu NetworkManager.service
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2142] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/19)
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2355] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2422] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2437] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2444] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2453] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2529] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2535] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2559] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2564] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 09 20:31:49 fedora NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1620617509.2585] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

```
traceroute youtube.com
traceroute to youtube.com (10.10.34.35), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (172.16.148.161)  110.442 ms  112.015 ms  112.743 ms
 2  92.223.89.1 (92.223.89.1)  114.433 ms  115.302 ms  116.738 ms
 3  10.255.8.182 (10.255.8.182)  118.095 ms  119.022 ms 10.255.8.181 (10.255.8.181)  120.942 ms
 4  10.255.8.177 (10.255.8.177)  122.864 ms  124.759 ms  125.409 ms
 5  149.6.67.153 (149.6.67.153)  127.591 ms  128.780 ms  129.219 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
```

purevpn log:

```
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 WARNING: file '/etc/purevpn/login.conf' is group or others accessible
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Dec 20 2017
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]92.223.89.8:53
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]92.223.89.8:53
Tue May 11 09:32:39 2021 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Tue May 11 09:32:40 2021 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1557', remote='link-mtu 1550'
Tue May 11 09:32:40 2021 WARNING: 'cipher' is used inconsistently, local='cipher AES-256-CBC', remote='cipher AES-256-GCM'
Tue May 11 09:32:40 2021 WARNING: 'auth' is used inconsistently, local='auth SHA1', remote='auth [null-digest]'
Tue May 11 09:32:40 2021 WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'
Tue May 11 09:32:40 2021 [Secure-Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]92.223.89.8:53
Tue May 11 09:32:41 2021 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue May 11 09:32:41 2021 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue May 11 09:32:41 2021 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 xxx.xx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.224 mtu 1500 broadcast 172.16.148.191
Tue May 11 09:32:41 2021 /etc/purevpn/pure-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1552 172.16.148.163 255.255.255.224 init
dhcp-option DNS 92.223.89.10
dhcp-option DNS 92.223.89.12
Tue May 11 09:32:41 2021 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Ping on VM that runs on Flatpak:

```
ping youtube.com
PING youtube.com (142.250.185.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s53-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.185.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=119 ms
64 bytes from fra16s53-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.185.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=119 ms
64 bytes from fra16s53-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.185.238): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=118 ms
64 bytes from fra16s53-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.185.238): icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=118 ms
```

Comment: Have you noticed any difference between IPv4 and IPv6?  Anything interesting with `traceroute`?  Anything interesting in OpenVPN log files?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I don't have `/var/log/openvpn.log` file but added `traceroute` and purevpn log.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any indirection/isolation that may be involved with this VPN, but isn't  IP address 10.10.34.35 kinda weird for youtube.com?  What happens if you ping 172.217.23.238?

Comment: Also, your OpenVPN and OpenSSL versions are pretty old.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @rickhg12hs pinging `172.217.23.238` works but when I use it on browser, it goes to Google, not YouTube. Added the YouTube ping on Flatpak VM to the question. btw, I think this app is using its own openvpn. The files they are providing doesn't work with 2.5.2.

Comment: There are so many possible points of failure.  Are you sure the FlatPaks are using the VPN?  Is everything being routed over the VPN, i.e., something isn't leaking out through another route?  Does PureVPN have a check website/procedure/program?  Why are some versions of software ancient?  If you view traffic via Wireshark/tshark/etc., do you see what you expect? All your configuration matches [PureVPN recommendations](https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-setup-purevpn-l2tp-on-linux-fedora-31)?  I don't use PureVPN but [this review](https://restoreprivacy.com/vpn/reviews/purevpn/) gives me pause.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Didn't know about that article! I purchased 5 years plan because it was working good on Ubuntu 20.04 :( They closed my support ticket and didn't solve my problem when I said you should update your openVPN and ovpn files. That been said. I'm sure flatpak apps are using VPN. I'm not sure if this is related or not. I don't have squid on my Fedora 34 installed but I see "ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved ... Generated ... by Prox-14-02-01 (squid/3.5.27)" when a domain name isn't correct. Maybe it is Fedora 34 default?